# Flutter: get the very last character input from the user

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using Flutter to make an app.
I want to set the very last character from the user as my state.

For example, when I type "apple" I want the character "e" to be my final state. When I move the cursor between "p" and "l" and type "x", I want the state to change to "x" and the content is "appxle"

I tried everything. I asked ChatGPT and [Bard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bard_(chatbot)), and still they don't have the answer. The best way I can think of is the get the event, but where can I get the event from? A controller?

Comment: See: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController-class.html, as well as https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController/selection.html. You can attach a listener to a `TextEditingController`, and use the selection property to update your state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an implementation you can use. See the comments in the code.

```
class CharacterAtCursor extends StatefulWidget {
  const CharacterAtCursor({super.key});

  @override
  State<CharacterAtCursor> createState() => _CharacterAtCursorState();
}

class _CharacterAtCursorState extends State<CharacterAtCursor> {
  /// Listened to in order to update the UI when the text field's text and/or
  /// cursor changes.
  final _textEditingController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    /// We add a listener so that whenever the text field's text or cursor
    /// changes, we update the UI.
    _textEditingController.addListener(() => setState(() {}));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    /// Dispose of the text editing controller.
    _textEditingController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text(
          _textEditingController.text.isEmpty
              ? "Type something"
              : _getCharacterAtCursor(), // Called to update the text.
        ),
        TextField(controller: _textEditingController),
      ],
    );
  }

  /// Extracts the character that is after the cursor.
  ///
  /// Modify the index to get the character before the cursor.
  String _getCharacterAtCursor() {
    final text = _textEditingController.text;
    final selection = _textEditingController.selection;
    final offset = (selection.baseOffset).clamp(0, text.length - 1);
    return text[offset];
  }
}
```